# Passing parameters from component to action creators

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm really struggling with Redux. I have one component where my input field is, and user should type in a word so I use that as a query in fetch request (which is in actionCreators file). I set that word to state so I want to pass that term to action and use it in fetch URL.

Component:

```
<button className='search-btn'
        onClick={() => 
this.props.getResults(this.state.searchTerm)}>


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getResults: (term) => dispatch(getData(term))
    }
}
```

actionCreators.js:

```
export const getData = (term) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch(`...url...${term}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
            console.log(data)

            dispatch({type: 'GET_DATA', results: data})
        })
    }
}
```

In reducer, I set data to be action.results.

All I get is `TypeError: dispatch is not a function`

Comment: are you using redux-thunk as middleware?

Comment: Yes I am. All worked really fine when I just sent and consoled results to test it, but as soon as I put in parameteres, all I get are errors.

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: "TypeError: dispatch is not a function"

Comment: @LotusFlower add the code showing how you connect the middleware.

Comment: export default connect (mapDispatchToProps)(Search);

Comment: @LotusFlower is this error thrown in Component or ActionCreator?

Comment: An error is thrown in component.At the top I've imported this: import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getData} from '../../store/actionCreators'; I really dont' get what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapDispatchToProps` is a second param to `connect`, the first is `mapStateToProps`:

```
default connect (null, mapDispatchToProps)(Search);
```

[Official docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect).

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct usage of connect.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Search);
```